# Difference between SQL Server 2008 Express R2 and SQL Server 2008 Enterprise R2 version

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

What are differences between SQL Server 2008 Express R2 and SQL Server 2008 Enterprise R2 version? Actually I want to know all exact limitations in Express version which are not in Enterprise version. Like Max DB file size etc

Comment: Start here - http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [SQL Server Editions Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx) which lists in great detail what the limitations of each edition are.

The most relevant limitations of the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition are:

- uses only 1 CPU
- can use max of 1 GB of RAM
- is limited to 10 GB of database size

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I want to know all exact limitations in Express

there are way to many differences between the free Express version and the Enterprise version, so just [go to this Microsoft SQL Server Compare Editions tool.](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx)